# order by makes query slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-indexes

I have two tables :

```
video (ID, TITLE, ..., UPLOADED_DATE)
join_video_category (ID (not used), ID_VIDEO_ ID_CATEGORY)
```

rows in video : 4 500 000 |
rows in join_video_category : 5 800 000

1 video can have many category.

I have a query works perfectly, 20 ms max to get result :

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_category WHERE ID_CATEGORY=11)
LIMIT 1000;
```

This query take 1000 video, the order is not important.

BUT, when i would like to get 10 latest video from a category, my query take arround 30-40 seconds :

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_category WHERE ID_CATEGORY=11)
ORDER BY UPLOADED_DATE DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I have index on ID_CATEGORY, ID_VIDEO, UPLOADED_DATE, PRIMARY ON ID video and join_video_category.

I have tested it with JOIN on my query, it's the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the comparisons are to two very different queries.  The first returns a bunch of videos whenever it encounters them.  The second has to read *all* the videos and then sort them.

Try rewriting this as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM video v JOIN
     join_video_category vc
     ON v.id = bc.id_video
WHERE vc.ID_CATEGORY = 11
ORDER BY v.UPLOADED_DATE DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

That may or may not help.  You have a lot of data and so you might have a lot of videos for a given category.  If so, a `where` clause that gets more recent data might really help:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM video v JOIN
     join_video_category vc
     ON v.id = bc.id_video
WHERE vc.ID_CATEGORY = 11 AND v.UPLOADED_DATE >= '2015-01-01'
ORDER BY v.UPLOADED_DATE DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Finally, if that doesn't work, consider adding something like `UPLOADED_DATE` into `join_video_category`.  Then, this query should blaze:

```
select vc.video_id
from join_vdeo_category vc
where vc.ID_CATEGORY = 11 
order by vc.UPLOADED_DATE desc
limit 10;
```

with an index on `join_video_category(id_category, uploaded_date, video_id)`.

Comment: OK, i choose to add UPLOADED_DATE into join_video_category table, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

solution #1: 
replacing "in" with "exists" would improve the performance, please try the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE exists
(SELECT * FROM join_video_category WHERE ID_CATEGORY=11 AND join_video_category.ID_VIDEO = video.ID)
ORDER BY UPLOADED_DATE DESC LIMIT 10;
```

solution #2:

1) create tem_table

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM join_video_category WHERE ID_CATEGORY=11;
```

2) use the temp table in solution #1

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE exists
    (SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.ID_VIDEO = video.ID)
    ORDER BY UPLOADED_DATE DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is 1:Many, don't use an extra table between Video and Category.  However, your row counts imply that it is Many:Many.

If it is 1:Many, simply have the category_id in the Video table, then simplify all the queries.

If it is Many:Many, then be sure to use *this* pattern for the junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE map_video_category (
    video_id ...,
    category_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(video_id, category_id),  -- both ids, one direction
    INDEX      (category_id, video_id)   -- both ids, the other direction
) ENGINE=InnoDB;  -- significantly better than MyISAM on INDEX handling here
```

The ID that you mentioned is a waste.  The composite keys are optimal for all situations, and will improve performance in most situations.

Do not use `IN ( SELECT ... )`; the optimizer does a poor job of optimizing it.  Change to a `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `EXISTS`, or some other construct.